# How to replace the | character in a cell with CHAR(10) in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to replace `|` with `CHAR(10)` in excel.

I tried `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",CHAR(10))`. but no luck. I need your help please

Input:

`Contrast v neck collar|Contrast front and back panels|Dropped shaped hem`

Desired output:

`Contrast v neck collar Char(10)Contrast front and back panels Char(10)Dropped`

Comment: Why did you try *that*? Why `,` instead of `|`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ";" as separator in function instead comma, Excel use it by default.
The Wrap Text parameter should be selected for final cell

Comment: this is not answer, please use comment section. Thanks!

Comment: The point about Wrap Text is useful, the other answer will not work without that setting on the cell.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|"," CHAR(10)")
```

*Output :-*

```
Contrast v neck collar CHAR(10)Contrast front and back panels CHAR(10)Dropped shaped hem
```

Or are you looking for this

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",CHAR(10))
```

*Output :-*

```
Contrast v neck collar
Contrast front and back panels
Dropped shaped hem
```

[image]

Comment: As @amyasoedov88 mentions in the other answer: "The Wrap Text parameter should be selected for final cell". For me, that setting was important to make the `SUBSTITUTE` and `CHAR(10)` approach work.